# Debug a Beta version of the managed package

Tags: managed-package, debugging, debug, beta-managed-package, debug-logs

Is it possible to debug a Beta version of the managed package? It seems that [LMA](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/lma_intro.htm) works only with those apps that were published on AppExchange.

Thank you.

Comment: Should be possible, AFAIK it does not matter if its beta or live version. Do you not see those org in subscriber list?

Comment: @Raul, thank you. Lol, what I did in my case was just to copy-paste the lightning components and classes into the beta test org and see how they work. It was enough to figure out the issue.

Comment: @Raul beta package versions don't appear in LMA, is there a way to see those in LMA?I can see there's a beta checkbox on package version object. Seems I'm missing something small.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which tool do you want to use.
If you want to use Subscriber Console, you may release one released package version, pass Security Review, and then create beta versions.
Those subscribers should be listed.

Another way is just simply use namespaced scratch org and deploy the source code there.